# Error Message doesn't show for factory Angular.js

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs

I've a factory method in my Code as:-

```
    (function () {
    var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);  
    app.controller('MYController', function ($scope, CourseDescFactory) {  // here $scope is used for share data between view and controller
        $scope.MyDescCourses = [];
        CourseDescFactory.OurCourses().then(function (d) {
            $scope.MyDescCourses = d.data;
            $scope.MainHeading = $scope.MyDescCourses[0].CD.MainHeading;
            $scope.MainDesc = $scope.MyDescCourses[0].CD.MainDesc;
            $scope.MainImg = $scope.MyDescCourses[0].CD.Img;

            $scope.MySubDescCourses = [];
            $scope.MySubDescCourses = $scope.MyDescCourses[0].CSD;
            //$scope.Img = $scope.MyDescCourses[0].Img;
        }, function (error) {
            alert('Cannot Load Course Detail');
        });
    })
.factory('CourseDescFactory', function ($http) {
    var CourseDescList = {};
    CourseDescList.OurCourses = function (id) {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/Home/CourseDesc',
            params: {}
        });
    }
    return CourseDescList;
});

})();
```

This works fine when I've data from backend . But when there is no data, instead of showing alert('Cannot Load Course Detail'); it throws an error 'Cannot read property 'CD' of undefined'.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: so I'm guessing on your .net HomeController  when you have a no data found scenario it is still returning a OK (or 200)  can you change your .net controller to throw BadRequest("no data found") when there is no data?

Comment: Yeah I was not sending any BadRequest. I figured that out later, thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to check your response variable which is "data" and it's inside content with the following commands.

```
     if (
         (d.data != undefined) && (d.data != null) && (d.data != "") 
        )
```

Comment: Yeah I figured out the mistake. Thanks for your answer.